# SublimeREPL not showing correctly

Tags: python, sublimerepl

I'm using Sublime3 to write and compile python code.
For some reason SublimeREPL doesn't show tabs correctly but cmd does. Why's that and how can I fix it?

```
    parantezeDeschise=0 # counts '('
    locatieParanteze=[] # location of '('
    for i in range(len(self.Propozitie)):
        print str(i+1)+'.',
        if self.Propozitie[i]=='(': # for every '(' there should be a TAB
            print (parantezeDeschise * '\t'),self.Propozitie[i],'cere formula compusa'
            parantezeDeschise+=1
            locatieParanteze.append(i)
        elif self.Propozitie[i]==')': # every ')' removes a TAB
            parantezeDeschise-=1
            print (parantezeDeschise * '\t'),self.Propozitie[i],'rezolva formula compusa [',locatieParanteze.pop()+1,']'
        else:
            print (parantezeDeschise * '\t'),self.Propozitie[i]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your SublimeREPL perhaps configured to display tabs as spaces? At the bottom right of your screen, does it show something like below?

[image]

If so, click where it says "Spaces". That should bring up the following context menu.

[image]

Just unselect "Indent Using Spaces" and going forward your SublimeREPL should show tabs correctly.

Comment: I don't know. How do I check?

Comment: I did that and nothing happend

Comment: Try changing the tab width to 8 and execute your commands again in the SublimeREPL